# How can I position child ul below parent ul with z-index

Tags: css

I am trying to position my child ul under the parent ul so I have

http://jsfiddle.net/hjJYN/

Code snipplet

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
li ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

but I still have my child ul above the parent, why is that. With plain old divs, I can use z-index ok why not with uls? http://jsfiddle.net/MjHBT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
ul {
    position: relative;
}
li ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

In other words, remove the `z-index` for the parent and give the child a negative `z-index`. This causes the hover of the sub menu to fail though and something about negative z-indices feels wrong.

Comment: ya ... I read somewhere -ve z-index dont work in FF2 and I guess it causes the lost of hover too

Comment: @jiewmeng, then I'm afraid what you want is impossible. The negative z-index is already a hack of sorts. It shouldn't be possible for a parent to be over its child.

Answer (score 1):

You could just the give the nested ul a margin-top:0, position it lower, and give it square corners. It would look fine then

Answer (score -1):

add to the child ul position:absolute;

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
li ul {
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Hmm its already positioned absolute, from the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hjJYN/